# Filter across all columns after a specific string

Tags: r

I am aiming to filter my data if I can find the string `Code` in any of the columns. It should filter at the first occurrence of this word.

I am working with a list and the columns containing `Code` change by their arrangement. So I need a general way to do this like the attempt.

Some example data:

```
# A tibble: 11 × 10
   `Title:`            `A&E weekly activity statistics, NHS…` ...3  ...4  ...5  ...6  ...7  ...8  ...9  ...10
   <chr>               <chr>                                  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 Contact:            Paul Steele - Unify2@dh.gsi.gov.uk     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
 2 NA                  NA                                     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
 3 Provider Level Data NA                                     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
 4 NA                  NA                                     NA    A&E … NA    NA    NA    A&E … NA    NA   
 5 SHA                 Code                                   Name  Type… Type… Type… Tota… Type… Type… Type…
 6 -                   -                                      Engl… 2831… 12906 1369… 4330… 15347 34    172  
 7 NA                  NA                                     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
 8 Q30                 RLN                                    City… 1423  669   297   2389  202   0     18   
 9 Q30                 RXP                                    Coun… 2473  0     2088  4561  89    0     0    
10 Q30                 5J9                                    Darl… 0     0     0     0     0     0     0    
11 Q30                 RR7                                    Gate… 1251  0     0     1251  24    0     0
```

My attempt:

```
vf %>% filter(row_number() >= across(everything(), ~ .x %>% which(. == 'Code')))
```

I get these error:

```
Error in `filter()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = row_number() >= ...`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Problem while computing column `Title:`.
Caused by error in `which()`:
! argument to 'which' is not logical
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Expected output:

```
# A tibble: 7 × 10
  `Title:` `A&E weekly activity statistics, NHS and indepen…` ...3  ...4  ...5  ...6  ...7  ...8  ...9  ...10
  <chr>    <chr>                                              <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 SHA      Code                                               Name  Type… Type… Type… Tota… Type… Type… Type…
2 -        -                                                  Engl… 2831… 12906 1369… 4330… 15347 34    172  
3 NA       NA                                                 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
4 Q30      RLN                                                City… 1423  669   297   2389  202   0     18   
5 Q30      RXP                                                Coun… 2473  0     2088  4561  89    0     0    
6 Q30      5J9                                                Darl… 0     0     0     0     0     0     0    
7 Q30      RR7                                                Gate… 1251  0     0     1251  24    0     0
```

Reproducible code:

```
structure(list(`Title:` = c("Contact:", NA, "Provider Level Data", 
NA, "SHA", "-", NA, "Q30", "Q30", "Q30", "Q30"), `A&E weekly activity statistics, NHS and independent sector organisations in England` = c("Paul Steele - Unify2@dh.gsi.gov.uk", 
NA, NA, NA, "Code", "-", NA, "RLN", "RXP", "5J9", "RR7"), ...3 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "Name", "England", NA, "City Hospitals Sunderland NHS Foundation Trust", 
"County Durham And Darlington NHS Foundation Trust", "Darlington PCT", 
"Gateshead Health NHS Foundation Trust"), ...4 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
"A&E attendances", "Type 1 Departments - Major A&E", "283175", 
NA, "1423", "2473", "0", "1251"), ...5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "Type 2 Departments - Single Specialty", 
"12906", NA, "669", "0", "0", "0"), ...6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"Type 3 Departments - Other A&E/Minor Injury Unit", "136985", 
NA, "297", "2088", "0", "0"), ...7 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "Total attendances", 
"433066", NA, "2389", "4561", "0", "1251"), ...8 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, "A&E attendances > 4 hours from arrival to admission, transfer or discharge", 
"Type 1 Departments - Major A&E", "15347", NA, "202", "89", "0", 
"24"), ...9 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "Type 2 Departments - Single Specialty", 
"34", NA, "0", "0", "0", "0"), ...10 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "Type 3 Departments - Other A&E/Minor Injury Unit", 
"172", NA, "18", "0", "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following attempt seems to get what I am after:

```
data %>% filter(row_number() >= which(keep(.,~any(which(.=='Code'))) == 'Code'))
```

however, I am sure there are cleaner attempts than this!

What I have done:

1. filter for row numbers greater than or equal to the logical vector containing `Code` in any of the columns.
2. `keep` retains the column that has `Code` in it, so `filter` can do its work.

Output:

```
# A tibble: 7 × 10
  `Title:` `A&E weekly activity statistics, NHS and indepen…` ...3  ...4  ...5  ...6  ...7  ...8  ...9  ...10
  <chr>    <chr>                                              <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 SHA      Code                                               Name  Type… Type… Type… Tota… Type… Type… Type…
2 -        -                                                  Engl… 2831… 12906 1369… 4330… 15347 34    172  
3 NA       NA                                                 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
4 Q30      RLN                                                City… 1423  669   297   2389  202   0     18   
5 Q30      RXP                                                Coun… 2473  0     2088  4561  89    0     0    
6 Q30      5J9                                                Darl… 0     0     0     0     0     0     0    
7 Q30      RR7                                                Gate… 1251  0     0     1251  24    0     0
```

Comment: This part `keep(., ~ any(which(. == 'Code')))` is logically and syntactically strange. A more valid version is `keep(., ~ any(. == 'Code', na.rm = TRUE))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_detect` to detect "Code" `across` all columns in combination with `if_any` to see if there is any column with the string and remove all rows before that specific row like this (Thanks to @Darren Tsai):

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
vf %>% 
  filter(row_number() >= which.max(if_any(everything(), str_detect, "Code")))
#> # A tibble: 7 × 10
#>   `Title:` `A&E weekly activit…` ...3  ...4  ...5  ...6  ...7  ...8  ...9  ...10
#>   <chr>    <chr>                 <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 SHA      Code                  Name  Type… Type… Type… Tota… Type… Type… Type…
#> 2 -        -                     Engl… 2831… 12906 1369… 4330… 15347 34    172  
#> 3 <NA>     <NA>                  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
#> 4 Q30      RLN                   City… 1423  669   297   2389  202   0     18   
#> 5 Q30      RXP                   Coun… 2473  0     2088  4561  89    0     0    
#> 6 Q30      5J9                   Darl… 0     0     0     0     0     0     0    
#> 7 Q30      RR7                   Gate… 1251  0     0     1251  24    0     0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

##### Old answer:

You can use `str_detect` to detect "Code" `across` all columns and remove all rows before that specific row like this:

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
vf %>% 
  filter(row_number() > if_all(everything(), ~!str_detect(., "Code")))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 10
#>   `Title:` `A&E weekly activit…` ...3  ...4  ...5  ...6  ...7  ...8  ...9  ...10
#>   <chr>    <chr>                 <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 SHA      Code                  Name  Type… Type… Type… Tota… Type… Type… Type…
#> 2 -        -                     Engl… 2831… 12906 1369… 4330… 15347 34    172  
#> 3 Q30      RLN                   City… 1423  669   297   2389  202   0     18   
#> 4 Q30      RXP                   Coun… 2473  0     2088  4561  89    0     0    
#> 5 Q30      5J9                   Darl… 0     0     0     0     0     0     0    
#> 6 Q30      RR7                   Gate… 1251  0     0     1251  24    0     0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This seems to remove the row with the string `Code`

Comment: @joe_bill.dollar, Check my updated answer! At first I misunderstood your question. Now it removes all rows before appearance of string.

Comment: I have a list of datasets just like this and I have eye-balled the speed of performing the function on the list. Your attempt definitely seems faster than mine

Comment: `if_all(...)` creates a logical vector and comparing it with `row_number`(row indices) is strange. I think a valid syntax is something like `df %>% filter(row_number() >= which.max(if_any(everything(), str_detect, "Code")))`.

Comment: @DarrenTsai, you are right! Updated answer according to your suggestion, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is a function `cumany` that can accomplish your task for you.

It returns TRUE for all cases after the first appearance of "Code"

```
df |> 
  filter(if_any(everything(), ~ cumany(.x %in% "Code")))
```

```
`Title:` `A&E weekly activity statistics, NHS and independent sector organisations in England` ...3          ...4  ...5  ...6  ...7  ...8  ...9  ...10
  <chr>    <chr>                                                                                 <chr>         <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 SHA      Code                                                                                  Name          Type… Type… Type… Tota… Type… Type… Type…
2 -        -                                                                                     England       2831… 12906 1369… 4330… 15347 34    172  
3 NA       NA                                                                                    NA            NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
4 Q30      RLN                                                                                   City Hospita… 1423  669   297   2389  202   0     18   
5 Q30      RXP                                                                                   County Durha… 2473  0     2088  4561  89    0     0    
6 Q30      5J9                                                                                   Darlington P… 0     0     0     0     0     0     0    
7 Q30      RR7                                                                                   Gateshead He… 1251  0     0     1251  24    0     0
```

Comment: This is a good attempt however I do not know which column contains `Code` in my dataset, because `Code` could be in any column, and so selecting specific columns would make it fail.

Comment: I missed that part,. See my updated version